# How to block a number from texting me in python via Twilio

Tags: python, python-2.7, twilio, twilio-api

I've been trying to find a way to block numbers that have texted my Twilio once,  so that I don't get charged after the first time because they will be blocked. I've checked around and seen that rejecting calls is possible, but I have yet to find anything that 'rejects' incoming sms's.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Twilio documentation](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181648-Is-there-a-way-to-block-incoming-SMS-on-my-Twilio-phone-number-) it is not possible to block SMS to a Twilio number selectively.

You are only able to toggle on/off SMS for an entire account or number.